# Unable to build or run teams app code in my mac using teams toolkit

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

I would like to use teams toolkit to debug my app locally.

but terminal throwing me error for all sample codes which i cloned and ran in my mac system.

Unable to launch debugger in vscode.

Sample screenshots shows you the issue.

[Teams Linked successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw82a.png)
[Terminal throwing error 127](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqgtm.png)

```
Executing task: npm run dev:teamsfx 


> sso-bot-sample@1.0.0 dev:teamsfx
> env-cmd --silent -f .localConfigs npm run dev

sh: env-cmd: command not found

 *  The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-l', '-c', 'npm run dev:teamsfx'" failed to launch (exit code: 127). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Need to run my successfully..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have not installed the `env-cmd` command line tools.

Try to run this command and try again.

```bash
npm i -g env-cmd
```

Comment: Alluri - Are you able to resolve this with this command?